# mint 13 xfce: cannot find or make trash bin

Tags: linux-mint, xfce, trash

I have a problem with removing files from some partitions. I get an error: cannot find or make trash bin.

I have searched google for this and found a site suggesting the partitions are mounted incorrect.

I have tried the suggestion offered there, but this did not solve the problem.

my fstab now looks like this (but is not correct):

```
#XP Systeem partitie
UUID=3280B49280B45DD3 /media/SYSTEEM/ ntfs-3g  defaults,uid=1000,gid=1000,dmask=027,fmask=137,users,exec,noauto,noatime 0 0

#Storage partitie
UUID=5D72C7913FF69127           /media/STORAGE/ ntfs-3g defaults,uid=1000,gid=1000,dmask=027,fmask=137,users,exec,noauto,noatime 0 0

#Multimedia partitie
UUID=79737B2129F73516           /media/MULTIMEDIA/ ntfs-3g    defaults,uid=1000,gid=1000,dmask=027,fmask=137,users,exec,noauto,noatime 0 0

#Video partitie
UUID=01CE758E211FEFB0           /media/VIDEO/ ntfs-3g      defaults,uid=1000,gid=1000,dmask=027,fmask=137,users,exec,noauto,noatime 0 0

#Backup partitie
UUID=01CE758E255A6510           /media/BACKUP/ ntfs-3g  defaults,uid=1000,gid=1000,dmask=027,fmask=137,users,exec,noauto,noatime 0 0
```

I hope I can solve this.

Comment: Have a look at: http://mynixworld.info/2012/09/16/fix-the-unable-to-find-or-create-trash-directory-in-thunar/

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. I solved it now some other way. I will post it when I'm home again.